# How to split an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app with a single site (a map application) and a big controller where I stored all the logic.
Because it was too big ( > 1000 lines of code), I decided to split it.

I made a divison in different parts, for example the creatiion of the markers, the comments on the markers, the search on them, user controll etc. and I want to create for every section a new file, but I also want them to share one single $scope.

I use the $routeProvider, where I defined one template with the old single big controller, but I don't know how to tell angular, that it should use all the new controllers I made.

I think I have an error in my reasoning building the structure. Can you tell me, how to devide the project the way I wish?
Thank you very much!

More spefic:
What I have:

```
 app.controller('bigController', ['$scope', 
 function ($scope) {
      $scope.var1;
      $scope.var2;

      $scope.function1 = function() {...};
      $scope.function2 = function() {...};
      $scope.function3 = function() {...};
      $scope.function4 = function() {...};
 }]);
```

What I want:

File 1:

```
 app.controller('controller1', ['$scope', 
 function ($scope) {
      $scope.var1;


      $scope.function1 = function() {...};
      $scope.function2 = function() {...};

 }]);
```

File 2:

```
 app.controller('controller2', ['$scope', 
 function ($scope) {
      $scope.var2;


      $scope.function3 = function() {...};
      $scope.function4 = function() {...};

 }]);
```

But I want access from to all $scope functions and variables in every controller and the HTML code should pick out the right function if I write

```
   <a ng-click="function4()">example</a>
```

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?  Post what you have and someone will be able to help out.

Comment: `$scope`s inherit from each other with prototypical inheritance, you can access properties of parent scopes from child scopes unless they're isolated.

Comment: @Khnle-KevinLe you're right, I added some examples.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum I don't want child scopes I want like one big <div ng-controller="controller1, controller2"> - Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not clear, you can use [ng-controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) to specify the controller for a specific section of your template, e.g:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeOtherController as other">
</div>
```

Not sure why you'd want anything in a single `$scope`, one can resort to `$rootScope` but it's a bad, bad design.

You can divide logic/data to several services, and have them injected to the various controllers handling each section, but without further information it's hard to tell.